# Zend: how do I share common code between view and action helpers?

Tags: zend-framework, view-helpers, actionviewhelper

I need a boolean from a combination of some configuration and a call to an external webservice.

The boolean is needed in the layout file of every view.  It is also needed in a select few controllers.

I have both an action and a view helper that get the required value from the external webservice.

Right now I have created both a view helper and an action helper with duplicate logic to check the external webservice and the configuration values, but it seems to me there should be a way to share that common code between helpers.

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to perform both tasks with the action helper. You might want to take a look at this blog post from MWOP: http://mwop.net/blog/235-A-Simple-Resource-Injector-for-ZF-Action-Controllers where he uses an action helper to assign resources from the bootstrap to the controller. You'd want to take a similar approach except that you'd be setting your boolean variable on the controller. You also access the View object from within the helper using:

```
$view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
$view->yourBooleanVar = 'whatever';
```

which you can then access in your views as normal.

Comment: Taking a look at this injection approach now.  I actually have two action helpers, one that checks the external service, and one that assigns the boolean.  Is this not correct?

Comment: And with this approach, I have to invoke the action helper from every controller in order to access the view?  I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: The second code example on the blog post linked invokes the action helper from a method in the bootstrap, so this would automatically run regardless of whether you need to use the helper in your controllers. Maybe if you can explain a little more what the boolean variables is for I could give a better example.

Comment: Turns out my use case is simpler than I thought, I can set the view variable in a preDispatch in the second helper and just check the view value in the few controllers that need it.  Thanks for the answer.